# Pushing array to list of arrays doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm reading a .txt file that is similar to this:

```
3 4
..--
..-.
-...
2 2
.-
-.
```

I'm splitting the rows and then I want to separate the rows in between the numbers and make an array of each of them. So basically I want an array that looks like this:

```
array = [["..--", "..-.", "-..."],[".-","-."]];
```

Here is my code:

```
var regex = /\d/g;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var row = x[i];
    if (regex.test(row) == true) {      
        numberArray.push(row);

        if (newArray == "") {
            console.log("New array is empty");
        } else if (newArray != "") {
            listOfArrays.push(newArray);
            newArray = [];
        }
    } else {
        newArray.push(row);
    }       
}
```

But when I console.log my `listOfArrays`, which contains two arrays, the first array is empty and the second one `["..--", "..-.", "-..."]`. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `if (newArray == "")` makes no sense. Why are you comparing an array to a string? And it will never be necessary, because the line before this was `newArray.push(row);`.

Comment: Did you previously define newArray as an empty array `[]`?

Comment: Yes i have previously defined var newArray = [];

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code as a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: What's a `list of arrays`? Semantics, I know, but there are no `lists` in js.

Comment: Previously I have this:
var listOfArrays = [[]];
and then my code to read a text file. And then:
var newArray = [];
var numberArray = [];
And then the code I provided above.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just using the wrong words, quite new to this, perhaps array of arrays is the right term.

Answer (score 0):

When the row contains numbers, you should just push `newArray` onto `listOfArrays`. You shouldn't push `row` onto `newArray` first. And the correct way to tell if an array is empty is by checking its length.

Finally, you need to push `newArray` onto `listOfArrays` at the end of the loop, since there's no row of numbers there.

```js
var x = [
  "3 4",
  "..--",
  "..-.",
  "-...",
  "2 2",
  ".-",
  "-.",
];

var regex = /\d/; // no need for g modifier when just using .test()
var listOfArrays = [];
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var row = x[i];
  if (regex.test(row)) {
    if (newArray.length == 0) {
      console.log("New array is empty");
    } else {
      listOfArrays.push(newArray);
      newArray = [];
    }
  } else {
    newArray.push(row);
  }
}
if (newArray.length > 0) {
    listOfArrays.push(newArray);
}

console.log(listOfArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the last inserted array in the result array or add an empty array if the last is not empty for matching items.

```js
var x = ['3 4', '..--', '..-.', '-...', '2 2', '.-', '-.'],
    i,
    result = [[]],
    regex = /\d/g;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!regex.test(x[i])) {
        result[result.length - 1].push(x[i]);
        continue;
    }
    if (result[result.length - 1].length) {
        result.push([]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```